# How to drag drop out of a frame in Java

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

Either this is not easy/can't be done/or I can't find the answer... I can drag drop an image INTO a frame and view it, but in this case I want to do the opposite - I want to drag what's in the frame and drop it onto the desktop as a specific type of document (in this case, a PDF).

Example:

[image: document in window]

This is an image of a pdf which I already know how to save manually as a pdf. It would be easier for my users to just drag that document onto the desktop as a pdf. Is this even possible and if so, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what kind of java application ui are you building? It is with swing?

Comment: javax.swing.jframe, yes.